# Regex: Substring the second last value between two slashes of a url string

Tags: ruby, regex, url, substring

I have a string like this:

```
http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value
```

How can I extract the `1234`?

Note: There may be a slash at the end:

```
http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value
http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value/
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Ruby, I'm just testing your answers now, Is there an easier way in ruby to substring based on the last tokens? which is more efficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$)
```

should work. You might need to format it differently according to the language you're using. For example, in Ruby, it's

```
if subject =~ /\/([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+\/?\Z)/
    match = $~[1]
else
    match = ""
end
```

Comment: Doesn't work if / is missing from the end. Edit - if you put all of those together :).. It works for single cases. +1

Comment: With your answer "http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value".match(/([^/]+)(?=/[^/]+/?$)) regex syntax fails on the ending of your regex

Comment: Yes, Ruby uses slashes to delimit a regex and uses different start/end of string anchors, that's why I asked. Will edit.

Comment: I took the leading slash out, here's what worked for me, thanks /([^\/]+)(?=\/[^\/]+\/?\Z)/

Comment: Why use a lookahead there? Could just as well remove it `/([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$`.

Answer (score 2):

### Use Slice for Positional Extraction

If you always want to extract the 4th element (including the scheme) from a URI, and are confident that your data is regular, you can use [Array#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-slice) as follows.

```
'http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value'.split('/').slice 4
#=> "1234"

'http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value/'.split('/').slice 4
#=> "1234"
```

This will work reliably whether there's a trailing slash or not, whether or not you have *more* than 4 elements after the split, and whether or not that fourth element is always strictly numeric. It works because it's based on the element's position within the path, rather than on the contents of the element. However, you will end up with *nil* if you attempt to parse a URI with fewer elements such as `http://www.example.com/1234/`.

### Use Scan/Match for Pattern Extraction

Alternatively, if you know that the element you're looking for is always the only one composed entirely of digits, you can use [String#match](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-match) with look-arounds to extract just the numeric portion of the string.

```
'http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value'.match %r{(?<=/)\d+(?=/)}
#=> #<MatchData "1234">

$&
#=> "1234"
```

The look-behind and look-ahead assertions are needed to anchor the expression to a path. Without them, you'll match things like `w3.example.com` too. This solution is a better approach if the *position* of the target element may change, and if you can guarantee that your element of interest will be the only one that matches the anchored regex.

If there will be more than one match (e.g. `http://www.example.com/1234/5678/`) then you might want to use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-scan) instead to select the first or last match. This is one of those "know your data" things; if you have irregular data, then regular expressions aren't always the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript:

```
var myregexp = /:\/\/.*?\/.*?\/(\d+)/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Works with your examples... But I am sure it will fail in general...

**Ruby edit:**

```
if subject =~ /:\/\/.*?\/.*?\/(.+?)\//
    match = $~[1]
```

It **[does](http://ideone.com/P4MS7)** work.

Comment: My input = top Q value above and your regex output gives me back ://www.example.ie/value/12345

Comment: Sorry, just not working both of them returned the same result,

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a little simpler than the accepted answer, because it doesn't use any positive lookahead (`?=`), but rather simply makes the last slash optional via the `?` character:

```
^.+\/(.+)\/.+\/?$
```

In Ruby:

```
STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |nextline|
   if nextline =~ /^.+\/(.+)\/.+\/?$/
    printf("matched %s in %s\n", $~[1], nextline);
   else
    puts "no match"
   end
end
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/a1DTgo)

---

Let's break down what's happening:

- `^`: start of the line
- `.+\/`: match anything (greedily) up to a slash

  - Since we're going to later match at least 1, at most 2 more slashes, this slash will be either the second last slash (as in `http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value`) or the third last slash as in (`http://www.example.com/value/1234/different-value/`)
  - Up to this point we've matched `http://www.example.com/value/` (due to greediness)
- `(.+)\/`: Our capturing group for `1234` indicated by the parenthesis. It's anything followed by another slash.

  - Since the previous match matched up to the second or third last slash, this will match up to the last slash or second last slash, respectively
- `.+`: match anything. This would be after our `1234`, so we're assuming there are characters after `1234/` (`different-value`)
- `\/?`: optionally match another slash (the slash after `different-value`)
- `$`: match the end of the line

---

Note that in a url, you probably won't have spaces. I used the `.` character because it's easily distinguished, but perhaps you might use `\S` instead to match non-spaces.

Also, you might use `\A` instead of `^` to match start of string (instead of after line break) and `\Z` instead of `$` to match end of string (instead of at line break)