# Regex excluding strings in between two slashes on URL

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting, regex-negation

I have a regex like this `basename/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$` but the problem is this is a greedy regex.
I want to exclude certain strings on the 2nd match such that if it matches one of the blacklisted strings, it will return false..

This problem is connected to my other question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102246/wordpress-returns-404-on-custom-rewrite-rules 
the only diffence is the approach.

Hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

**EDIT:** here is what im trying to work from: `basename/(.+)/!(string1|string2|string3).*/(.+)/?$` (added from comments)

P.S. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345262/regex-substring-the-second-last-value-between-two-slashes-of-a-url-string) but this doesn't seem like what I wanted.

Comment: make it ungreedy with the `U` modifier

Comment: i've integrated the comment into the question.. please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first if/else regex condition, cool right :) ?
`basename\/(.+)\/(?(?=(?:bar|string2|string3)\/)^|(.+))\/(.+)\/?$`

So what does this mean ?

- `basename\/` : match `basename/`
- `(.+)\/` : anything until `/` found and match `/`
- `(?(?=(?:bar|string2|string3)\/)^|(.+))` : the tricky part, we'll split this up:

  - `(?` : This means *if*
  - `(?=(?:bar|string2|string3)\/)` : positive lookahead, check if there is `bar/` or `string2/`, or `string3/`.
  - `^` : If the lookahead succeeded, then match this. `^` means begin of line, since we are in the middle of a string, this will *always* return false !
  - `|(.+)` : Else, match everything until ...
  - To sum it up, we check if there is `bar/` or `string2/` or `string3/`, if there is a match then we'll look for begin of line `^` which will always return false (our intention) else match further `(.*)`
- `\/(.+)\/?$` : match `/`, then anything until `/` optionally. `$` means end of line.

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/pO0hD9)

Comment: at first i thought it wasn't working.. but i just need to escape the slashes.. this is great. thanks! +1 more for the regex tester. this was way better than the one i'm using.

Comment: @reikyoushin thanks :) You may use other delimiters for example `#` so you wouldn't need to escape `/` (of course you then shall escape `#` if necessary !).

Comment: actually i use # already. ;) btw, how come my tester couldn't recognize the `g` in the options (gm), im using these before http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: @reikyoushin In PHP there is no `g` modifier, the `g` modifier exists in JavaScript which means "match all". If I didn't put the `g` modifier in the online tester, it would only match the first instance. In PHP you would use `preg_match` to match one instance, and `preg_match_all` to match all instances (which is `g` in JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make catch group that has the same pattern (/dir) lazy matches (using ?).

For strings such as:

```
basename/dir1/dir2/dir3/
basename/dir1/string1/dir3/  
basename/dir1/string2/dir3/
```

The following Regex would return false for the second two but catch the first:

```
basename/(.+?)/(?!string1|string2|string3)(.+?)/(.+?)/$
```

PHP fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/1qr-iip

Comment: Problem is, this will not match `basename/dir1/string1cool/dir3/`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `.*?` instead of `.*` to make it ungreedy, but you'd probably be better with a greedy match that excludes `/`.  ie `[^/]*`.

Your question is not all that clear.  I'm not sure what you're doing with the `!(x|y|z)` construct.  That `!` is a literal.  Is that what you intended?